# Finding C++ references in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

In eclipse C++ (with CDT), I would like to find all C++ references of the selected text. Ideally with the following constraints:

- accessible via keyboard shortcut
- a working set can be selected to restrict the search
- I do NOT need to right click on my working set directory in Project Explorer > Index > Update with Modified Files, so that search results are relevant

Currently, I know:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> : but it searches in the whole project which is just huge. For those who know Visual Assist Plugin in Visual Studio, it is more or less the equivalent of shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> except Visual Assist indexer seems really faster to me, and I have never been bothered by the latency before.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, then Enter : cool but if I can skip the Enter, and have a direct shortcut somehow, it would be just better

So, I have three questions:

1. Have you got this issue, in a big project with thousands of files, that the indexer gets in a wrong state (it is not in a running step who could explain that, it just seems wrong), so that if you modify a file, a next references search shows weird results, except if your right click on a directory in Project Explorer > Index > Update with Modified Files ? I tried to play around with Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Indexer but had not luck to improve that.
2. Is it possible to have a shortcut for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, then Enter ?
3. If not, is it possible to record/tune some kind of macro to avoid repeating these uncomfortable and distracting steps ?

Thanks,

Eclipse details:

```
Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
CDT Version: 8.6.0.201502131403
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to find "References in Project" instead of in the whole workspace. If you have several projects in your workspace, the search is slower than in only one project. First try `References > In Project` from the context menu to see if this command works well enough for you.

If you are satisfied with it, assign a hot key in menu `Windows -> Preferences > General > Keys`. Filter by text "References in Project", select the item with "Source" category. Change its hot key below and change "When" field to "C/C++ Editor".